# php regex to match three words if not then two and then one

Tags: regex

Q1: I'm writing a regex in php and not successful. I want to match the following:

```
    so i would
```

if not then match:

```
    so i
```

and then:

```
    i would
```

and

```
    so
    i
    would
```

Here is my code:

```
\b(so i|i would|so i would|(so|i|would))\b
```

Its only matching the: so, i, would, so i, i would .... but not matching the so i would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order your regex correctly.

```
\b(so i would|so i|i would|(so|i|would))\b
```

Put the longest string to match  to the left.
The `|` is left-associative and hence, in your version Of the regex, is matching the shorter string.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it at the beginning

```
\b(so i would|so i|i would|(so|i|would))\b
```

Answer (score 0):

put longest pattern to left in the group: \b(long|...|short)\b 
another solution: `\b(so i would|i would|would|so i|so|i)\b` 
p.s. this is NFA regex engine feature, please refer to "Mastering Regular Expressions"